# How to invalidate cache in kernel driver?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have an output buffer in my kernel driver. And that share with my hardware, which uses it for output.

When I got an interrupt, the kernel driver will copy the data from the output buffer to user space buffer.

How can I invalidate cache after my kernel driver copy the output buffer?

Comment: Which cache, the CPU dcache or some other cache? If you allocated the buffer with `kmalloc` and `GFP_KERNEL`, and used `copy_to_user` to transfer the data to the userspace buffer then there is no cache problem.

Comment: Did you read the [DMA API documentation](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt)?

Answer (score 0):

I used `dmac_inv_range()`.  Pass the beginning and the end of the area you want to invalidate.

Comment: It looks like the dmac_inv_range() was deprecated a long time ago. It last appeared in linux 2.6.33.